# Convert different categorical variables to dummy variables

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression

I am trying to apply regression (with XGBRegressor) to the following dataset containing 3 categorical variables.

**X_data**

```
severity -> values S1,S2,S3
priority -> values P1,P2,P3
cluster -> values a,b,c,d
```

**y_data**
the labels to predict are numerical values

In order to convert all 3 columns to categorical I use:

`pd.get_dummies(X_data['thecolumn'],drop_first =True)`

After converting all of them I end with 7 new columns (considering that im dropping always the first column). When applying the algorithm, could a column from priority or cluster be misinterpreted as the third column of severity? Maybe I dont understand the concept but I can't see how the reference is kept and i'm afraid i'm not doing it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. The column from priority or cluster won't be misinterpreted as the third column of severity.

Here's answer to how reference is kept:

in `pandas.get_dummies` there is a parameter i.e. `drop_first` allows you whether to keep or remove the reference (whether to keep k or k-1 dummies out of k categorical levels).

Please note `drop_first = False` meaning that the reference is not dropped and k dummies created out of k categorical levels! You set `drop_first = True`, then it will drop the reference column after encoding.

Here's link to [one hot encoding](https://hackernoon.com/what-is-one-hot-encoding-why-and-when-do-you-have-to-use-it-e3c6186d008f).

As in your case `severity` has 3 categories S1, S2 and S3.
After creating dummies one of these categories will always be 1 and others 0.

for s1 it will be [1,0,0], s2 will be [0,1,0] and s3 will be [0,0,1]

Now if you drop the column for category s1.

The values will be [0,0] if severity is S1

[1,0] if severity is S2

[0,1] if severity is S3.

So there is no information loss here and your model has one less column to deal with.
That's why it is always recommended to keep `drop_first` parameter as `True`.

**Edit** :

After applying the dummies you will get columns like:

```
severity_S1   severity_S2   severity_S3  

  1              0              0                  # when value is S1
  0              1              0                  # when value is S2  
  0              0              1                  # when value is S3
```

`pandas.get_dummies()` drops the 1st column after creating the above references.
So in your data will be like below:

```
 severity_S2   severity_S3

   0              0                  # when value is S1
   1              0                  # when value is S2  
   0              1                  # when value is S3
```

For all there variables your final data will look like below:
**I'm using short column names due to space issue**:

```
s2  s3  p2  p3  B  C  D
0   0   1   0   1  0  0     # For row with S1, P2 and B
0   1   0   1   0  1  0     # For row with S3, P3 and C
1   0   0   0   0  0  1     # For row with S2, P1 and D
1   0   0   0   0  0  0     # For row with S2, P1 and A
```

Comment: And what would happen if I reorder the columns in the dataframe? for example s2, p3, p2, s3. Would p3 be interpreted as s3? From your answer I assume that the columns need to be in order, right?

Comment: not at all. Model takes care of it. You need not worry about it. You can keep the columns in any order. That's the beauty of machine learning.

Comment: thanks! (and sorry that I insist), but i dont get how. if s3 is the [0,0,1] of severity and p3 is the [0,0,1] of priority. How ist the reference kept if I reorder the columns?

Comment: I think you misunderstood. Let me edit the answer for better explanation.

Comment: yeah, now I get it, ty!